# Reference request: lattice theory of the algebra of open sets in a subspace of the Baire space

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, lattice-orders, descriptive-set-theory, the-baire-space

I'm interested in lattice-theoretic properties of the algebra of open sets in a subspace of the Baire space $\Bbb N^{\Bbb N}$ can or cannot have.  What is a good source on this matter?  (An Internet search like "locale Polish space" did not reveal much.)

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance, but I don't know what the meaning is of $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ .

Comment: @HandeBruijn $\Bbb N^{\Bbb N}$ is the topological space of functions from naturals to naturals with the product topology.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by saying that you are interested in the **lattice theoretic properties of the open subsets of the Baire space**? Is there a difference to saying one is interested in the **topology of the Baire space**?